# foreach( B in list<A>) with B inheriting from A

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is possible to use foreach in c# which focuses only on a specific type of objects which inherit from the type of the list?
i tried this but i had a casting error : (B inherites from A)

```
list<A> myAs;
class B:A{}    
foreach (B b in myAs)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

thank you

Comment: runtime casting error?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ's [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) extension method. It will return a new IEnumerable instance with only elements of the specified type:

```cs
foreach (B b in myAs.OfType<B>()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate B instances in your A list. So, list A contains more than one type based on A. You have to filter list first and iterate or use IEnumerable.OfType(System.Linq namespace) method.

```
foreach (B b in myAs.OfType<B>())
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through it as a usual List of As, but check also if they are Bs. And if not, continue:

```cs
class A {}
class B : A {}
List<A> MyList;

foreach (A myA in MyList)
{
 if (!(myA is B))
  continue;

 // TODO
}
```

OR use LINQ instead (`TypeOf`, as mentioned in another answer):

```cs
foreach (B myB in MyList.OfType<B>())
{
 // TODO
}
```